# Amadeus-Flight-Post Booking-Adding Frequent Flyer Number In a PNR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, soap, amadeus

I've created a flight PNR(and is end transacted) with Amadeus SOAP Api. Now I want to add a Frequent Flyer Number(fnn) to one of the passengers in this PNR. For this, I've called `PNR_AddFrequentFlyer` SOAP api. Please see the below procedures that I've taken so far.

1. Called `PNR_AddFrequentFlyer` SOAP Api with proper data.
2. Got Successful Response.
3. End Transacted the call(`Security_SignOut`) with the session credentials got from `PNR_AddFrequentFlyer`.
4. After that, I called fetch pnr(`PNR_Retrieve`) api and the response xml got no ffn of that passenger.

My problem is with no 4. Although I get successful response from `PNR_AddFrequentFlyer`, why no ffn is showing in `PNR_Retrieve` api calling xml response?

I've read the doc for [`PNR_AddFrequentFlyer`](https://developers.amadeus.com/functional-doc/24/doc-read/98377?serviceVersion=4.1) and found out this piece of info showed in the screenshot. Here it says, a commit transaction is needed. [image]

So, what is this **Commit Transaction**? I thought the commit transaction is the `Security_SignOut` api call. But it seems not to be working. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you working on Enterprise API?

Comment: you gonna want to take a look a PNRAction 11 (END and Retrieve) this commits the action made to the PNR